# Cannot infer contravariant Nothing type parameter

Tags: scala, scala-compiler

Consider the following snippet:

```
trait X[-T]
object Y extends X[Nothing]
def a[T](x: X[T]): X[T] = x
a(Y)
```

Compilation of the above (2.12.3) fails with:

```
type mismatch;
found   : Y.type
required: X[T]
   a(Y)
     ^
```

This compiles fine if:

- a different type than `Nothing` is used (e.g. `object Y extends X[String]`)
- the method `a` doesn't use `T` in its return type (e.g. `def a[T](x: X[T]): Unit = {}`)
- the type parameter for `a` is explicitly given (i.e. `a[Nothing](Y)`)
- `T` is covariant, not contravariant (also fails if it's invariant)

Is this some special case in the compiler for `Nothing`?

As an "interesting" work-around, the following seems to work fine:

```
trait X[-T]
object Y extends X[Nothing]
def a[T, U <: T](x: X[T]): X[U] = x
a(Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain the code line by line

Line 1: `trait X[-T]` -> trait X is contravariant in type T. So you can replace any variable of type X[T] with its subtype. In case of contravariant types, Z[A] is subtype of Z[B] if B is subtype of A.

Line 2: `object Y extends X[Nothing]` -> object Y is of type X[Nothing]. Please note that Nothing is subtype of all other types.

Line 3: `def a[T](x: X[T]): X[T] = x` -> define an expression which takes arguments of type X[T]. Because trait X is contravariant in type T, you can also pass subtypes of X[T] i.e. X[N] such that T is subtype of N

Line 4: `a(Y)` -> Call expression 'a' with argument of type X[Nothing]. Since the compiler does not know the type of argument of 'a', it can not decide if X[Nothing] is subtype of X[T]. There are multiple ways to resolve this

```
Solution 1: `a[Nothing]` -> explicitly defining the type

Solution 2: `tait X[+T]` -> make X covariant in type T. In this case Z[A] is subtype of Z[B] if A is subtype of B. This will work because Nothing is subtype of any other type
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why using `String` instead of `Nothing` makes the example compile? Or why does the work-around work?